# Applying CIFilter to UIImage results in resized and repositioned image

Tags: ios, swift, cifilter, ciimage

After applying a CIFilter to a photo captured with the camera the image taken shrinks and repositions itself.

I was thinking that if I was able to get the original images size and orientation that it would scale accordingly and pin the imageview to the corners of the screen. However nothing is changed with this approach and not aware of a way I can properly get the image to scale to the full size of the screen.

```
func applyBloom() -> UIImage {
  let ciImage = CIImage(image: image) // image is from UIImageView

  let filteredImage = ciImage?.applyingFilter("CIBloom",
                                              withInputParameters: [ kCIInputRadiusKey: 8,
                                                                     kCIInputIntensityKey: 1.00 ])
  let originalScale = image.scale
  let originalOrientation = image.imageOrientation


  if let image = filteredImage {
    let image = UIImage(ciImage: image, scale: originalScale, orientation: originalOrientation)
    return image
  }

  return self.image
}
```

Picture Description:
Photo Captured and screenshot of the image with empty spacing being a result of an image shrink.

[image]

Comment: Remove the `scale` and `orientation` parameters in your conversion from `CIImage` to `UIImage` and things will be fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this. Replace:

```
func applyBloom() -> UIImage {
    let ciInputImage = CIImage(image: image) // image is from UIImageView
    let ciOutputImage = ciInputImage?.applyingFilter("CIBloom",
                                          withInputParameters: [kCIInputRadiusKey: 8, kCIInputIntensityKey: 1.00 ])
    let context = CIContext()
    let cgOutputImage = context.createCGImage(ciOutputImage, from: ciInputImage.extent)
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgOutputImage!)
}
```

- I remained various variables to help explain what's happening.
- Obviously, depending on your code, some tweaking to optionals and unwrapping may be needed.

What's happening is this - take the filtered/output CIImage, and using a CIContext, write a CGImage the size of the input CIImage.

- Be aware that a CIContext is expensive. If you already have one created, you should probably use it.
- Pretty much, a UIImage *size* is the same as a CIImage *extent*. (I say pretty much because some generated CIImages can have *infinite* extents.)
- Depending on your specific needs (and your UIImageView), you may want to use the output CIImage extent instead. Usually though, they are the same.

Last, a suggestion. If you are trying to use a CIFilter to show "near real-time" changes to an image (like a photo editor), consider the major performance improvements you'll get using CIImages and a `GLKView` over UIImages and a `UIImageView`. The former uses a devices GPU instead of the CPU.

Comment: I appreciate the detail of the explanation greatly! Solution worked about 90%. just like previous attempts I've had with creating a context the output would rotate the image 90 degrees. simple fix of orientation did the trick.

And I might have to do some research on using a CIContext and also an EAGLContext to use the GPU over the CPU to figure out the best plan of attack. Thank you very much, all the info you provided helped a lot!

Comment: @lifewithelliott, here's a good link for CoreImage: https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/core-image-intro/ Towards the top is a link to a GitHub project where they subclassed GLKView as FilteredImageView. It has settings to work with different contentModes (aspectFit, aspectFIll, etc.) along with setting up an EAGLContext and CIContext.

Comment: I’ve recently discovered CIFilters being performed on images updated through the camera’s image uses a standard iPhone camera resolution. This doesn’t match the pixel or point resolution at all. For instance, iPhone 6s plus used 1280x720.

Comment: @VagueExplanation that sounds like a good question to ask here on SO. I have an iPhone SE and iPhone 7 plus, along with an iPad Mini and iPad 10.5 inch. If you include some code (and make sure you tag the question [core-image]) I'll do my best to help.

Comment: Thanks dfd, it's not really a question, but just some input on the experience I had with this. @lifewithelliott said the solution worked 90%, but I believe that's because the solution coincidentally worked better than what they had before, but using the camera's output resolution could make it work 100%.

Answer (score 1):

This could also happen if a `CIFilter` outputs an image with dimensions different than the input image (e.g. with `CIPixellate`)

In which case, simply tell the `CIContext` to render the image in a smaller rectangle:

```swift
let cgOutputImage = context.createCGImage(ciOutputImage, from: ciInputImage.extent.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 20))
```